# Does there exist an LR(k) grammar with no LL(1) equivalent

Tags: c, parsing, context-free-grammar, ll-grammar, lr-grammar

I haven't been able to find an answer to this yet. Are there grammars that are context free and non-ambiguous that can't be converted to LL(1)?

I found one production that I couldn't figure out how to convert into LL(1): the `parameter-type-list` production in C99:

```
parameter-type-list:
    parameter-list
    parameter-list , ...
```

Is this an example of an LR(k) grammar that doesn't have an LL(1) equivalent or am I doing something wrong?

edit: I copied the wrong name, I meant to copy parameter-declaration:

```
parameter-declaration:
    declaration-specifiers declarator
    declaration-specifiers abstract-declarator(opt)
```

the problem is with declarator and abstract declarator both having ( in their first set, but also being left recursive.

Comment: It is recommended to put the example/code in your question instead of putting a link.

Comment: First question possibly answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809545/example-of-an-lr-grammar-that-cannot-be-represented-by-ll

Comment: Full set of comparisons (no examples): https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43/language-theoretic-comparison-of-ll-and-lr-grammars/48#48

Comment: @deniss the grammar that guy lists as non LL(1) is ambiguous, so it's not really conclusive

Comment: @Bobby Sacamano, why is it ambiguous? Bison with `canonical-lr` accepts it with no conflicts.

Comment: "aab has two different parse trees, with either of the first two alternatives of S at the root" - Gunther

Comment: @Bobby Sacamano, that claim is about old post version, where it was `S ::= a S b | a S | \epsilon`

Comment: oh I misread the timestamp. Is there a way to prove that there exists no LL(1) equivalent for this though?

Comment: @Bobby Sacamano, http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3350/is-this-language-ll1-parseable

Answer (score 4):

In general, `LR(k)` grammars are more powerful than `LL(k)`. That means there are languages with `LR(k)` parser, but not `LL(k)`.

One of the examples are language defined with grammar:

```
S -> a S 
S -> P
P -> a P b
P -> \epsilon
```

Or, in other words, string of `a`'s, followed by the same or less number of `b`'s. That follows from the fact that `LL(k)` parser must make a decision about every `a` encountered - is it paired with some `b` - looking ahead no more than `k` symbols of input, but they also can be `a`'s, giving no useful information.
For strict proof, look at the second part of accepted answer here https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3350/is-this-language-ll1-parseable

Your example, however, can be simply [left factored](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser#Left_Factoring) in LL(1) grammar to be

```
parameter-type-list -> parameter-list optional-ellipsis
optional-ellipsis -> \epsilon
optional-ellipsis -> , ...
```

One note that `FOLLOW` set for `parameter-list` will contain `,` character, and this can cause `FIRST-FOLLOW` conflict. If it is the case, then we need to see `parameter-list` definition to fix this conflict too.

**Edit:** `parameter-declaration` rule seems very complicated to answer right away. You can try to perform left factorization by hands for all conflicting alternatives, or with some assistance tool, like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/index.html).